# Angular output is not displaying as expected

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angularjs. I was trying some codes in Angularjs. But I'm getting the result as binding expressions.

Script.js is displaying as followed.

```
        /**
        * 
        */

        // <reference path="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js" />

        //Create the module
        var myApp=angular.module("myModule",[]);

        //Create the Controller
        var myController=function($scope){

        $scope.message="Angular Js Tutorial";

        var employee= {

        firstname : "Hiroshi",
        lastname : "Perera" , 
        gender : "Male"

        };

        $scope.employee=employee;

        };


        ////Register model with the controller. Name of the Controller 'MyController'.
        myApp.controller("myController1",myController); 

        //Creating everything in a single line.

        var myApp2=angular
        .module("myModule2",[])
        .controller("myController2",function($scope){

        var father={

        firstname: "Lakshman ",
        lastname : "Perera",
        gender   : "Male"
        };
        $scope.father=father;   

        });


        var myapp3=angular
        .module("ModImage",[])
        .controller("ControllerFlower",function($scope){


        var flowerDetails={


            flowerName: "Roses",
            Colour : "prik",
            flower:"Images/boquet.jpg"
        };

        $scope.flowerDetails=flowerDetails;
        });
```

following is the html file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    head >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/Script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-ng-app="">
        <div>
            10+20={{ 1==2 }}
        </div>
        <div>
            10+20={{ 10+20 }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{{name:'Hiroshi',age:'28'}.name}}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ ['Hiro','Thili','Thamali'][1] }}
        </div>

    </div>  
        <div ng-controller="myController1" data-ng-app="myModule">
            <div>{{message}}</div>

            <div>My First Name : {{employee.firstname}}</div>

            <div>My Last Name : {{employee.lastname}}</div>

            <div>My Gender : {{employee.gender}}</div>
        </div>

        <div data-ng-app="myModule2" ng-controller="myController2">


            <div>Father's First Name : {{father.firstname}}</div>

            <div>Father's Last Name : {{father.lastname}}</div>

            <div>Father's Gender : {{father.gender}}</div>

        </div>

        <div data-ng-app="ModImage" ng-controller="ControllerFlower">


            <div>Name : {{flowerDetails.flowerName}}</div>

            <div>Colour : {{flowerDetails.Colour}}</div>

            <div>Image : {{flowerDetails.flower}}</div>

        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm getting the out put as following.

```
    10+20=false
    10+20=30
    Hiroshi
    Thili
    {{message}}
    My First Name : {{employee.firstname}}
    My Last Name : {{employee.lastname}}
    My Gender : {{employee.gender}}
    Father's First Name : {{father.firstname}}
    Father's Last Name : {{father.lastname}}
    Father's Gender : {{father.gender}}
    Name : {{flowerDetails.flowerName}}
    Colour : {{flowerDetails.Colour}}
    Image : {{flowerDetails.flower}}
```

Can someone please let me know the mistake I had done.I was trying this in several ways ways but still was unable to get the expected output.

Comment: why do you need multiple ng-app in your page? is it requirement  for the project?

Comment: No it was not a project. This was only a practice code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using `angular.bootstrap` instead. AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.

To have multiple instances of the AngularJS app running on the same 
page you would have to use manual bootstrap as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).

you need to add following two lines in `script.js` file

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("myModule2"), ['myModule2']);
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("ModImage"), ['ModImage']);
```

Please check codepen [here](https://codepen.io/santoshshinde2012/pen/YxwKEG) for your demo.

Hopes this will help you !!

Comment: Hi it worked. And when one data-ng-app is used everything worked. Does it mean that of a particular html (view file) we can fetch data only from a single module ? If another module need to be used, do I need to use another html by following he MVC architecture?

Comment: Actually angular is single page application so by default it's bootstrap single app for more it's need to manual bootstrap